# Load typescript files dynamically on click event

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a scenario where I have to load a typescript file dynamically on a click event. When a button is clicked the event handler based on some criteria should decide which typescript file to load and load that. any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: Your question isn't clear at all. Where are you trying to load it in? What do you mean under **load**?

Comment: Create button. Create way to select the path to the script. Create a new `<script>` html node. Set the src of the tag to the path to the script. Insert the html node into the page. Script should get downloaded and executed.

Comment: You should not load a typescript file, you should load a javascript file. Other than that your question isn't clear enough.

Comment: sorry about that, I have recently started working with typescript and I am totally lost. May be my question doesn't make sense or I am not sure how to put it up. I ll revise it.